# React native createMaterialTopTabNavigator, replace text with image

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've been trying to make my top tab navigation and I want to make it so that instead of text there are images. This is the current code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
View,Text,Image
} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

function Screen1(){
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>This is Screen1</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function Screen2(){
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>This is Screen2</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function Screen3(){
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>This is screen 3</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function Screen4(){
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>This is screen 4</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function MyTabs() {
  return (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Tab.Navigator>
      <Tab.Screen name="Screen 1" component={Screen1} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Screen 2" component={Screen2} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Screen 3" component={Screen3} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Screen 4" component={Screen4} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default MyTabs;
```

and this is the current result (for anyone wondering) again what I'm trying to do is replace the Screen 1,2,3,4 with images but I can't seemingly find how.
[Current Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDEDo.png)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: why arent you using react-native-tab-view ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `tabBarLabel` on each screen's `options` prop like this:

```
import image1 from './image1.png';
import image2 from './image2.png';

// ...

const CustomTabLabel = ({image}) => {
  return <Image source={image} style={{width: 50, height: 50}} />;
};

function MyTabs() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen
          options={{tabBarLabel: () => <CustomTabLabel image={image1} />}}
          name="Screen 1"
          component={Screen1}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          options={{tabBarLabel: () => <CustomTabLabel image={image2} />}}
          name="Screen 2"
          component={Screen2}
        />
        // Your other screens...
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

For more info check the documentation here: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/material-top-tab-navigator/#tabbarlabel.